# Is Guava Cache allowed to be used in EJB 3.0

Tags: multithreading, caching, static, ejb-3.0, guava

In our project, we would like to create a cache for LDAP information, and seems Guava is a good choice.

However, I have some concerns since we are using EJB 3.0.

Basically, we have one UserDAO class, which is responsible to get necessary LDAP information, and a Guava Cache is declared as static in UserDAO.

Could I simply use this UserDAO in ejbs? I have two concerns:
1. ejb does not allow read/write static field, in case ejbs are run in multiple JVMs. the UserDAO has the static cache already.
2. ejb does not allow generating user's own Threads, and I think this rule extends to not using MultiThread library? I am not sure how Guava Cache is implemented?

Thank you!

Comment: Technically, the thread management is performed by Guava: you don't perform the management yourself. Also, avoid `static`, try to use a `@Singleton` to wrap your cache implementation. For instance, look at http://blog.iadvise.eu/2014/01/13/caching-in-a-jee-dont-write-it-yourself-use-loadingcache-from-google-guava-libraries/.

Comment: Thank you Olivier! However, @Singleton is not available in ejb 3.0 yet, I guess. Also, even Guava is managing the threads, they are still threads not known by the ejb container?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's proper to use Guava Cache in EJB.

Although Guava Cache doesn't create new Thread, it manages Thread. There are `sychronized` block and `ReentrantLock` in the cache. So it is not proper behavior in EJB.